# Java ,Spring Framework Calling Oracle Stored Procedure with CURSOR as input Parameter

Tags: java, spring, oracle, plsql, java-stored-procedures

Normally, we register cursor as an out parameter to retreive the values from oracle stored procedure.

Below code is for Spring:

```
RowMapper<?> rowMapper = new DataRowMapper(tableName);

declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(DAOConstants.DROP_DOWN_CURSOR, OracleTypes.CURSOR,rowMapper));
compile();
```

How can we supply create cursor in spring/java and pass as input parameter to the oracle stored procedure?